# Proper way to add a custom listener to a Kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, listener

I'm a Kotlin noob (third day) and trying to add a listener to my class.

I'm currently using lambdas as in the following example and they work fine.

```
// Declare callback
class Controller {
   var onAction = { -> }
}

// Use callback
myController.onAction = {
   ...
}
```

However, I really like the way Android's `Button::setOnClickListener` is consumed in Kotlin code as follows (without having to use `=`):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    awesomeObject.doSomething()
}
```

This makes me wonder:

**How do I declare my listener so it can be used the `Button::setOnClickListener` way?**

**What is the most 'Kotlinic'(*) way? Mine or `Button::setOnClickListener` way?**

(*) As in Pythonic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fun setOnAction(block: () -> Unit) { onAction = block }` and keep your `onAction` `var`.

But I suppose it's more Kotlin-idiomatic to just keep what you have. Properties are usually preferred over setter `fun`s. The Android Button syntax is the result of SAM conversion of Java code. `setOnClickListener` ends up more concise than `onClickListener =` only because with the latter, the listener is a Java interface you have to name rather than a Kotlin function. It's really verbose to write:

```
button.onClickListener = OnClickListener {
    //...
}
```

so the SAM conversion is nicer to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use next syntax to add a custom listener:

```
class Controller {
    var onAction1: () -> Unit = {} // listener with default implementation without params and returns Unit

    var onAction2: (() -> Unit)? = null // nullable listener without params and returns Unit

    var onAction3: ((Int) -> String)? = null // listener with param of type Int and returns String object
}
```

Initializing listeners:

```
val controller = Controller()
controller.onAction1 = {
    // your action
}

controller.onAction2 = {
    // your action
}

controller.onAction3 = { intParam ->
    // your action
    "result" // return some String result
}
```

Calling listeners:

```
val controller = Controller()
controller.onAction1()
controller.onAction2?.invoke()
val result: String? = controller.onAction3?.invoke(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

For all you TL;DR people, here is a full example based on @Tenfour04's answer on how to use it without needing the `=` sign (emulating SAM conversion):

```
// Declare callback using SAM's 

class Controller {

    // The listener
    private var onAction: () -> Unit = {}

    // This will allow you to use without the '=' 
    // (as in required in Sergeys answer)
    fun setOnAction(block: () -> Unit) { onAction = block }

    // A listener with params
    private var onActionWithParam: (String) -> Unit = {}

    // This will allow you to use without the '=' 
    // (as in required in Sergeys answer)
    fun setOnActionWithParam(block: (String) -> Unit) { onActionWithParam = block }

}

// use the listener without '='
controller.setOnAction {
  something.awesome()
}

controller.setOnActionWithParam { paramName ->
  something.awesomeRequireStr(paramName)
}
```

However, bear in mind that the most Kotlin-idiomatic may be actually @Sergey's answer.