# Kotlin Dialog On Dismiss Listener

Tags: android, kotlin, event-listener, android-dialogfragment

I created a custom dialog and I need to do something back in the fragment that called that dialog, when the dialog is dismissed. I tried a number of things I translated from Java but most didn't work or were deprecated. Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

DialogFragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

onAccept() {
   //do some things
   onDismiss()
}

companion object {

        private const val TAG = "My Dialog Fragment"

        fun show(
           
        ) {
            MyDialogFragment().apply {
                //args
            }.show(fragment.parentFragmentManager, TAG)
        }
    }
}
```

In the fragment it just called as follows:

```
class doStuffFragment : AppFragment {

   fun showDialog(){
      MyDialogFragment.show(this)
   }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you should never use `show(fragment.parentFragmentManager, TAG)` - always add your `DialogFragment` using the `fragment.childFragmentManager` instead of to the parent FragmentManager.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this by creating custom onDismiss listener in the Dialog and setting it in the "parent" fragment.

Note: I am using a bit different approach to creating dialog, but adding listener should work in your case too.

Adding listener to dialog:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    private var onDismissFunction: () -> Unit = {}

    fun setOnDismissFunction(block: () -> Unit){
        onDismissFunction = block
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        onDismissFunction()
        super.onDismiss(dialog) 
    }
```

Setting the listener in the main fragment:

```
val dialog = MyDialogFragment()
dialog.setOnDismissFunction {
    // your code
}
dialog.show(this.supportFragmentManager, MyDialogFragment.TAG)
```

Based my answer on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62491119/4601890)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onCancel()` method in your corresponding Dialog Fragment.
you can get more details by [Clicking here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface))

```
override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onCancel(dialog)
        //Your code goes here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fragment to show dialog, you should use `childFragmentManager`, that will provide new `FragmentManager` inside `Fragment`.

```kotlin
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    fun showDialogFromFragment() {
        DialogFragment()
            .show(this.childFragmentManager, TAG)
    }
}
```

Beside that, in case of you are wanna show dialog inside `Activity`, `supportFragmentManager` is your choice.

```kotlin
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun showDialogFromActivity() {
        DialogFragment()
            .show(this.supportFragmentManager, TAG)
    }
}
```